# Regenerate session id after or before setting a secure value

Tags: php

This is a very specific question regarding when exactly to call `session_regenerate_id()`. Is there a difference or security risk between calling `session_regenerate_id()` before or after setting a secure value in session.

Before setting a value:

```
if ($login_success) {

    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['login_status'] = 'logged_in';

}
```

Or after setting a value in session:

```
if ($login_success) {

    $_SESSION['login_status'] = 'logged_in';
    session_regenerate_id(true);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works, `session_regenerate_id()` will create and change the session id, transferring the session to the new file and send out the cookie. Passing `true` as an argument will also delete the old session file, omitting the argument will leave it.

So, whether you use

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION['login_status'] = 'logged_in';
```

or

```
$_SESSION['login_status'] = 'logged_in';
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

it is the same: info is rewritten to the new file and the cookie is sent out. I'd advise using `true` as argument though at all times, to avoid old session hijacking.

Comment: your answer is perfectly correct and i am thankful for the input but it did not adres the actual issue. To avoid confusion for other programmers, I changed the answer. No pun intended (I upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 1):

They are effectively the same; session information is actually persisted only when calling session_write_close() (or implicitly when the script ends). So the data would not get persisted for the old id.

Comment: Hi @obe can you please confirm if session_regenerate_id() implicitly calls session_write_close() and session_start() or would i have to combine regenerate, change value, close and start session to persist the changes directly?

Comment: @Nitin, This is PHP, your transaction will end soon and send the headers (cookie) out to the client. So, imo, no need to close and restart the session after a regenerate.